# How to put other controls on top of the video?

Tags: vb.net, video, mcisendstring

I am using mciSendString to play a video but I am unable to put any control like labels or buttons on top of the video. How do I put another control on top of the video ?

Below is the code:

> Public Class Form1
>
> Private Declare Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias
>   "mciSendStringA" (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal
>   lpstrReturnString As String, ByVal uReturnLength As Integer,ByVal
>   hwndCallback As Integer) As Integer
>
> Dim filename As String
>
> Dim retVal As Integer
>
> ```
> Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
>     filename = Chr(34) & "D:\farm.wmv" & Chr(34)
>     retVal = mciSendString("open " & filename & " type mpegvideo alias movie parent " & Panel1.Handle.ToInt32 & " style child", 0, 0, 0)
>
>     retVal = mciSendString("put movie window at 0 0 201 127", 0, 0, 0)
>     retVal = mciSendString("play movie", 0, 0, 0)
>  End Sub   End Class
> ```

Before : (Button 1 is visible)

[image]

After : (Button 1 is no longer visible)

[image]

Comment: Why would you want a control to be on top of the video? Did you try the [`BringToFront` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx)?

Comment: @CodyGray I require my form window to be 200 x 150, so I have less space for the video and the buttons, so I need them to be on top of the video. Replacing the panel with a picture box seems to solve my problem (tried that after posting the question)

Answer (score 0):

Sets the index of the specified child control in the collection to the specified index value.

`Control.ControlCollection.SetChildIndex` Method

For instance if button is inside picture box control then just set:

```
PictureBox.Controls.Setchildindex(control,newIndex)
```

This will do the job.